# Detecting orientation on loading

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uideviceorientation

When my simulator is in `portrait` and when my `viewcontroller loads initially`, it prints out `Landscape` instead of `Portrait` but when I change the orientaiton, it correctly displays the orientation so forth. I did the following

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
  super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

  if (UIDevice.current.orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.portrait || UIDevice.current.orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.portraitUpsideDown)
  {
    print("Portrait")
  }
  else
  {
    print("Landscape")
  }
}
```

I have no idea why it is displaying wrong orientation when it loads initially but once I rotate everything seems to work.

P.S. It seems like when simulator initially loads, the orientaiton is `unknown`, so it is choosing the `else condition`, how to avoid this from happening and identify the correct orientaiton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check current orientation by [`UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation.isPortrait`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiinterfaceorientation/1625048-isportrait) or [`UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation.isLandscape`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiinterfaceorientation/1625039-islandscape).

Comment: Where do I put these, can you elaborate?

Comment: @Coder221, try to replace your `if` condition with it.

Comment: This works, so device orientation is not reliable initially?

Comment: @Coder221, not exactly. If you check the [`UIDeviceOrientation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uideviceorientation) (type of `UIDevice.current.orientation`), you see that it has not only portrait and landscape orientations, but some others. That's why your code doesn't work as you expected.

Comment: You are right, so is it better to use status bar orientationas it has only landscape and portrait and the device detects them regardless the device orientation is unknown or faceup or facedown?

Comment: Appreciate your elaboration on this topic :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation.isLandscape.boolValue {
    print("landscape")
} else {
    print("portrait")
}
```

Comment: what will you get for UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation at viewDidLayoutSubviews

Comment: I dont have  UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation at viewDidLayoutSubviews. Is it necessary?